# How to use multi combo boxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am implementing a windows application in `C#.Net`. I have three tables: country, state, District. They all are related with foreign keys.
The problem is in the District form if i select one country(combobox), the related state is not displayed in another combobox. I used `selectedindexchange` event for state table. But it shows

> **"Input String is not in a correct format"**

I will give a code in below. So please help me.

```
private void DistrictMaster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BEMaster objBEMaster = new BEMaster();
    BLMaster objBLMaster = new BLMaster();
    cboCountryName.DataSource = objBLMaster.GetCountry();
    cboCountryName.ValueMember = "CountryId";
    cboCountryName.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
}

private void cboCountryName_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (cboCountryName.SelectedValue.ToString() != "")
        {
            BEMaster objBEMaster = new BEMaster();
            objBEMaster.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(cboCountryName.SelectedValue);
            BLMaster objBLMaster = new BLMaster();
            cboStateName.DataSource = objBLMaster.GetStateByCountryId(objBEMaster);
            cboStateName.DisplayMember = "StateName";
            cboStateName.ValueMember = "StateId";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;
    }                    
}
```

Is there any error in the above please give me reply.
Thanks.

Comment: In which line you are getting error

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: objBEMaster.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(cboCountryName.SelectedValue);

Answer (score 1):

As advice, the line

`if (cboCountryName.SelectedValue.ToString() != "")`

could be replaced in:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboCountryName.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

About your problem, from your description it isn't clear where the problem is, but I think this line is your problem:

```
objBEMaster.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(cboCountryName.SelectedValue);
```

Instead, use the [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, not to handle the exception and check if the problem is a conversion issue:

```
int myCountry;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(cboCountryName.SelectedValue, out myCountry);
if(result)
{
  BEMaster objBEMaster = new BEMaster();
  objBEMaster.CountryId = myCountry;
  BLMaster objBLMaster = new BLMaster();
  cboStateName.DataSource = objBLMaster.GetStateByCountryId(objBEMaster);
  cboStateName.DisplayMember = "StateName";
  cboStateName.ValueMember = "StateId";
}
```